# ipfw logs on Snow Leopard

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ipfw

where can I find the ipfw logs on Snow Leopard?
it is not in
/var/log/system.log

and this file is completely empty

```
/var/log/ipfw.log
```

Answer (score 1):

While `/private/var/log/ipfw.log` is also listed in `Console.app` (even though it's also empty for me), some messages regarding firewall activity are stored in `/private/var/log/appfirewall.log`. Maybe that's what you're looking for.